# Spark Java API. Access last Element of RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on Spark SQL (2.2) using Spark Java API.

`RDD.first()` or `RDD.take(1)` gives the first item, is there a straight forward way to access the last element in a similar way?

I coudn't fine a tail/last method for RDD.

I need to use RDD because I need to check if the last line of my my file contains "\r" or "\n". If I use DataFrame of Dataset Spark delete the "\r" and "\n".

Here is how I load data using spark Java API.

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(session.sparkContext());
    Configuration hadoopConf = new Configuration();
    hadoopConf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", separateur);
    JavaRDD<String> rdd = jsc
            .newAPIHadoopFile(fecpath, TextInputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, hadoopConf).values()
            .map(r -> r.toString());
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. There is indeed no last(), but can you sort it differently and get the first? Why do you need to use RDD (specially in v2.2), can you use dataframes (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html). Maybe if you share a little bit of code, we could help you better.

Comment: I updated my post and explained why I need to use RDD. Thanks